# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato del <input type="time"></input> del reloj molesto por el de la introducción manual con teclado?

Tags: angular, ionic

¡Hola! Llevo un tiempo viendo en mi aplicación de Angular con Ionic este formato con el relojito en el input (Ver 1 en la imagen), imagino que gracias al método de introducción de datos de Android de Google de mi móvil, el que muestro en la siguiente imagen...

La cuestión es que me sale la posibilidad de seleccionar el teclado abajo a la derecha del modal, pero quiero que de forma predefinida salga el teclado (Ver 2 en la imagen) y no sé cómo configurarlo... ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? ¡Muchísimas gracias!
Dejo mi código debajo de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

```
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col style="text-align: center; padding: 0px;" size="6">
          <p style="font-size: 20px;">
            <ion-icon class="coloricon" name="enter-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input [(ngModel)]="time_in" type="time">
          </p>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col style="text-align: center; padding: 0px;" size="6">
          <p style="font-size: 20px;">
            <ion-icon class="coloricon" name="exit-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input [(ngModel)]="time_out" type="time">
          </p>
        </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
```